# Saving json array to c# class object

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have to assign json array of string to a c# class. I have done like below. But I got an exceptio

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'LoggedInUserDetails' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.\r\nPath '', line 1, position 1."}

```
public class LoggedInUserDetails
{
    public string login_user_name
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public string login_user_id
    {
        get; set;
    }
}

 var GetResponse = await response2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
//"[{\"login_user_name\":\"Rahul\",\"login_user_id\":\"43\"}]"
 LoggedInUserDetails obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoggedInUserDetails>(GetResponse);
 Variables.login_user_name = obj.login_user_name;
 Variables.login_user_id= obj.login_user_id;
```

Comment: It's a JSON array. How could you represent an array in C#?

Comment: your json is a list, so var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LoggedInUserDetails>>(GetResponse);

Comment: Error tells you everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It because of the '[]', which stores it as a array of results. You should be able to do something like the following:

```
LoggedInUserDetails obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LoggedInUserDetails>>(GetResponse);
```

where you try to deserialize object as an list. The list will only contain 1 object.

full example:

```
public class LoggedInUserDetails
{
    public string login_user_name
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public string login_user_id
    {
        get; set;
    }
}

 var GetResponse = await response2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
//"[{\"login_user_name\":\"Rahul\",\"login_user_id\":\"43\"}]"
 List<LoggedInUserDetails> obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LoggedInUserDetails>>(GetResponse);
 Variables.login_user_name = obj[0].login_user_name;
 Variables.login_user_id= obj[0].login_user_id;
```

Answer (score 3):

You should `deserialize` the *json* string to an *IEnumerable* collection or `Array`.

```
 var content = await response2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LoggedInUserDetails>>(content);
```

Comment: I wouldn't say that OP *should* deserialize to a `List`, but *could*. One can deserialize to any collection, such as `LoggedInUserDetails[]`, `IEnumerable<LoggedInUserDetails>` and so on...

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
LoggedInUserDetails obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoggedInUserDetails[]>(GetResponse).FirstOrDefault() ?? throw new Exception("User not found.");
Variables.login_user_name = obj.login_user_name;
Variables.login_user_id = obj.login_user_id;
```

Your result was an array containing 1 object, so you just had to convert it to an array of your desired object and take the first.

Comment: Guys instead of editing my answer, read the code please. Your edits were completely wrong.

Comment: Indeed, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using array, then it should deserialize array  to list 
    public class Test 
    {
       public string login_user_name {get; set;}
       public string login_user_id { get; set;}
    }

```
string js =  "[{\"login_user_name\":\"Rahul\",\"login_user_id\":\"43\"}]";
var result  =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Test>>(js);
foreach(var ob in result)
{
  Console.WriteLine(ob.login_user_name);
  Console.WriteLine(ob.login_user_id);
}
```

output

```
Rahul
43
```